# Filter a complicated data structure

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

given a random datastructure (can be realy anything):

```
const data = [
 {
  name: "John",
  age: 26,
  company: {
   name: "Some company",
   address: "Some address"
  }
 },{...}
];
```

I would like to be able to search in all values of the object and sub objects. For instance if the user types in John, I'd like to return all objects containing "John", and if the User searches for "Some company", I'd like to return the all objects containing theses as well.

I was thinking about flatten the structure ob each object and afterwards filter the original list, but this somehow doesn't feel right. Any suggestions?

Comment: I would write a recursive function that traverses through all the object's keys. What have you tried so far? Can you share your code? As you know as an experienced user, SO is not a code writing service :-)

Comment: Here you can find several solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39546088/how-to-filter-json-object-in-javascript/39546684

Comment: @PatrickHund I was not expecting code, I was expecting suggestions like u just did;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a recursive search for objects with [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values).

```js
var data = [{ name: "John", age: 26, company: { name: "Some company", address: "Some address" } }, { name: "Jane", age: 32, company: { name: "Cameo", address: "2nd Root Dr" } }],
    find = 'Cameo',
    result = data.filter(o => Object.values(o).some(function search(v) {
        return v && typeof v === 'object' ? Object.values(v).some(search) : v === find;
    }));
  
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Wow. This is indead a neat solution. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a path to search, for example:

```
search(data, "name", "John"); // search for object with names equal to "John"
search(data, "company.adress", "some adress"); // search for objects with company adresses equal to "some adress"
// ...
```

The code for that will be:

```
function path2value(obj, path) {
    return path.split(".").reduce((o, p) => (o? o[p]: undefined), obj);
}

function search(arr, path, value) {
    return arr.filter(o => path2value(o, path) === value);
}
```

**Example:**

```js
const data = [{
  name: "John",
  age: 26,
  company: {
    name: "Some company",
    address: "Some address"
  }
}, {
  name: "Ibrahim",
  age: 23,
  company: {
    name: "Some company",
    address: "Some address"
  }
}];

function path2value(obj, path) {
  return path.split(".").reduce((o, p) => (o ? o[p] : undefined), obj);
}

function search(arr, path, value) {
  return arr.filter(o => path2value(o, path) === value);
}

console.log(search(data, "name", "John"));
console.log(search(data, "company.name", "Some company"));
```

**EDIT:**

If you don't want to pass in a `path` and you want to filter the object recursevly. You can make a function that go over all the values in the object and their subobjects and pass them to a callback (where you can specify whether or not to include that object), if the callback returns true, then the root object will be included in the result array, otherwise it won't. The use of such function will be as follow:

```
filterRecursive(data, value => value === "John"); // filter the objects by value equals to "John"
filterRecursive(data, value => typeof(value) === "number" && value > 20); // filter the objects by values that are numbers and greater than 20
filterRecursive(data, value => /^Some/.test(value)); // filter the objects with values that start with "Some"
```

the function would be:

```
function filterRecursive(arr, cb) {                                   // takes an array and a callback and recursively call the callback on each value in the object and sub object
    function hasIt(obj) {                                             // take an object and recurseively call the callback cb on its values and its subobjects values returning true if one of those values returned true, false if none of them returened true
        for(let key in obj) {                                         // for each key in the object
            if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {                             // if the key is owned by this object
                if(Object.prototype.toString.call(obj[key]) === "[object Object]") {  // if the value on this key is another object...
                    if(hasIt(obj[key])) return true;                  // then call hasIt on it and if it returned true then return true and stop the search for this object
                }
                else if(cb(obj[key])) return true;                    // otherwise, if it's not an object, then pass it to the callback, if the callback returned true, then return true and stop the search
            }
        }
        return false;                                                 // return false if the recursive search failed
    }

    return arr.filter(o => hasIt(o)); // filter the root object by whether they have it or not (hasIt)
}
```

**Example:**

```js
function filterRecursive(arr, cb) {
  function hasIt(obj) {
    for (let key in obj) {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        if (Object.prototype.toString.call(obj[key]) === "[object Object]") {
          if (hasIt(obj[key])) return true;
        } else if (cb(obj[key])) return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  return arr.filter(o => hasIt(o));
}

const data = [{
  name: "John",
  age: 26,
  company: {
    name: "Some company",
    address: "Some address"
  }
}, {
  name: "Ibrahim",
  age: 23,
  company: {
    name: "Some company",
    address: "Some address"
  }
}];

console.log(filterRecursive(data, v => v === "John"));
console.log(filterRecursive(data, v => /^Some/.test(v)));
```

Comment: This is a neat solution. However, the point is that I don't want the need to give a key where to search. Instead I want to search in every value :)

Comment: @Christian Check out the **EDIT:** section above!

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```js
function getObjectValues(obj, values){
  for(var key in obj){
    let value = obj[key];
    if(typeof value === "object"){
      getObjectValues(value, values);
    } else {
        values.push(value)
    }
  }
  return values;
}
    
const data = [ 
 {
  name: "John",
  age: 26,
  company: {
   name: "Some company",
   address: "Some address"
  }
},
{
  name: "Bar",
  age: 27,
  company: {
   name: "Some company",
   address: "Some address"
  }
},
{
  name: "Foo",
  age: 28,
  company: {
   name: "Some company John",
   address: "Some address"
  }
}];

let filteredData = data.filter(function(obj){
    return getObjectValues(obj,[]).some(function(value){
        return value.toString()
                    .includes("John");
    });
});


console.log(filteredData);
```